# Ubuntu 20.04 WSL2: Accidently changed root user to nonexistent shell

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell, wsl2

While trying to change my default shell from bash to fish on WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04, I royally messed up and accidentally used `sudo chsh /bin/fish <user>`. I'm assuming there was no such thing as /bin/fish because now every time I try to open Ubuntu, it immediately closes. Now that I have no default shell, how can I possibly change my shell back to either bash or to fish (honestly would take either at this point, I just want a shell back)?

Comment: Unfortunately, by changing the shell for root, you have made it impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Welp, I finally got it. For those who unfortunately make the same mistake I do, here's what you have to do.

1. Open a PowerShell prompt as administrator
2. Change your directory to your WSL distribution with the command `cd \\wsl$\<Distribution>`. For me this was running the command `cd \\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04`.
3. Make sure the distribution you're trying to access is the default WSL distribution, and if not, make it so temporarily
4. Run the command `wsl --user root` - This will give you root access to all your WSL files within the PowerShell prompt
5. Edit `/etc/passwd` and set the shell to be something usable, I set mine to `/bin/bash` but you can see what is usable in the `/etc/shells` file
6. After saving the file, quit, and reopen WSL. It should work again like a charm!

Comment: Steps 2 and 3 are actually not needed.

Answer (score -1):

Boot from a LiveCD, mount your partition, edit its `/etc/passwd` and change `/bin/fish` to `/bin/bash` (or fish if it's really installed, but I would keep the change to a minimum). Reboot.

Comment: How would I go about booting from a LiveCD on Windows WSL2? I've tried changing the /etc/passwd file from the windows file explorer in the \\wsl$ directory, however, I don't have the proper permission to do that

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that it was in WSL. `/etc/passwd` is the file to change. It can usually only be edited by root. From Windows side I think you will have to edit it as administrator (such as opening an elevated notepad and then opening the file).

Comment: Even from an elevated notepad, I'm getting ```\\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04\etc\passwd
You don't have permission to save in this location. Contact the administrator to obtain permission.```